# Merging columns Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, time, merge

I have the following Dataframe:
df1

| startTimeIso | endTimeIso | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-07T03:28:56.969000 | 2023-03-07T03:29:25.396000 | 5 |
| 2023-03-07T03:57:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T03:59:08.734000 | 7 |
| 2023-03-07T04:18:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T04:20:10.271000 | 16 |
| 2023-03-07T07:58:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T07:58:10.271000 | 21 |

and the second one:
`df2`

| startTimeIso | endTimeIso | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-07T03:28:57.169000 | 2023-03-07T03:29:25.996000 | true |
| 2023-03-07T03:57:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T03:58:08.734000 | true |
| 2023-03-07T05:38:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T05:40:10.271000 | true |
| 2023-03-07T07:58:08.934000 | 2023-03-07T07:58:10.371000 | true |

I want to check, if a row from df2 merge with a row from df1. There can be a tolerance from 1 Second. StartTimeIso as well as endTimeIso should be considered.

The result should look like this:
`df_merged`

| startTimeIso | endTimeIso | value | startTimeIso_y | endTimeIso_y | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-07T03:28:57.169000 | 2023-03-07T03:29:25.996000 | true | 2023-03-07T03:28:56.969000 | 2023-03-07T03:29:25.396000 | 5 |
| 2023-03-07T03:57:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T03:58:08.734000 | true | None | None | None |
| 2023-03-07T05:38:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T05:40:10.271000 | true | None | None | None |
| 2023-03-07T07:58:08.934000 | 2023-03-07T07:58:10.371000 | true | 2023-03-07T07:58:08.734000 | 2023-03-07T07:58:10.271000 | 21 |

Rows_found = 2

Comment: For clarity can you provide an example for which end is considered differently than start? Here a simple merge on start OR end is sufficient

Comment: @mozway Can you modify the code so that the end of the values must match a tolerance of 1 second?
Currently only the startTimeIso is checked, but the end can be as long as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### one-to-one merge using `merge_asof`

Use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `tolerance`:

```
df1[['startTimeIso', 'endTimeIso']] = df1[['startTimeIso', 'endTimeIso']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df2[['startTimeIso', 'endTimeIso']] = df2[['startTimeIso', 'endTimeIso']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

out = pd.merge_asof(
    df2.sort_values(by='startTimeIso'),
    df1.sort_values(by='startTimeIso')
       .rename(columns={'startTimeIso': 'startTimeIso_y'}),
    left_on='startTimeIso', right_on='startTimeIso_y',
    direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s'),
    suffixes=(None, '_y')
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
             startTimeIso              endTimeIso  value            endTimeIso_y    id
0 2023-03-07 03:28:57.169 2023-03-07 03:29:25.996   True 2023-03-07 03:29:25.396   5.0
1 2023-03-07 03:57:08.734 2023-03-07 03:58:08.734   True 2023-03-07 03:58:08.734   7.0
2 2023-03-07 05:38:08.734 2023-03-07 05:40:10.271   True                     NaT   NaN
3 2023-03-07 07:58:08.934 2023-03-07 07:58:10.371   True 2023-03-07 07:58:10.271  21.0
```

If you want to consider either start or end, perform two merges and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out1 = pd.merge_asof(
    df2.sort_values(by='startTimeIso').reset_index(),
    df1.sort_values(by='startTimeIso')
       .rename(columns={'startTimeIso': 'startTimeIso_y'}),
    left_on='startTimeIso', right_on='startTimeIso_y',
    direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s'),
    suffixes=(None, '_y')
)

out2 = pd.merge_asof(
    df2.sort_values(by='endTimeIso').reset_index(),
    df1.sort_values(by='endTimeIso')
       .rename(columns={'endTimeIso': 'endTimeIso_y'}),
    left_on='endTimeIso', right_on='endTimeIso_y',
    direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s'),
    suffixes=(None, '_y')
)

out = out1.combine_first(out2).set_index('index')

print(out)
```

##### many-to-many merge using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

```
s1 = df1['startTimeIso'].to_numpy()[:,None]
s2 = df2['startTimeIso'].to_numpy()
e1 = df1['endTimeIso'].to_numpy()[:,None]
e2 = df2['endTimeIso'].to_numpy()

ms = abs(s1-s2) < pd.Timedelta('1s')
me = abs(e1-e2) < pd.Timedelta('1s')

idx1, idx2 = np.where(ms&me)

out = df2.join(df1.iloc[idx1].set_axis(df2.index[idx2])
                  .rename(columns={'startTimeIso': 'startTimeIso_y',
                                   'endTimeIso': 'endTimeIso_y'}))
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the two columns startTimeIso of the data frames are merged using merge_asof. Is there a way to include the column endTimeIso in the merge, so that the end time is also taken into account?
Because when I tried the first example, only the startTimeIso has to match. The endTimeIso does not play a role.

Comment: @hubi3012 it depends if you are trying to do a one-to-one or one-to-many or many-to-many merge. `merge_asof` only supports one to one. Can you give more details, eventually updating your example?

Comment: When I look at your solution, the 2 line in df2 is matched with the 2 line in df1. Now I have adjusted the times in my df1 so that this should no longer be matched, since startTimeIso in the two dfs matches but endTimeIso in the two dfs does not, since the end time of the two entries is different, even taking into account the tolerance. I hope I can give you more clarity with this. I would like to see if both the startTimeIso and the endTimeIso match during the merge.

Comment: The many-to-many merge solution is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately no, that would be a different logic

Comment: can you perhaps give me an example of this?

Comment: You should probably open a new question with specific examples